# Звук без учета вкладки

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

День добрый. Каким образом можно проиграть звук в браузере с той вкладки, на которой пользователь не находится в данный момент ? На деле выходит, что звук проигрывается тогда, когда пользователь находится на необходимой вкладке или совершает на ней какие либо действия..

По задумке Что - то типа уведомления..

Comment: А может приведете пример кода, который надеюсь у Вас есть. Или Вы просто хотите сразу готовое решение?

Comment: Так получается, если для воспроизведения звука использовать тег **embed**, но с тегом **audio** это не происходит. Или может используется **flash**?

Comment: А событие, выводящее уведомление, в неактивной вкладке работает? Скажем, если проверить алертом.

Comment: Вообще, это ограничения браузерной политики. Вы не можете проигрывать звук ни с того ни с сего с только что открытой страницы. Потому что большинству юзеров это только мешает.

Comment: К тому же, сперва это начало касаться только тега аудио, а сейчас обнаружил, что взялись и за embed.

Comment: Всем спасибо...